# Share location в мессенджерах

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Такой вопрос, как правильно делать Share location в мессенджерах, а именно, как потом это отображать в ленте чата. Например в WhatsApp это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понимаю, координаты отправляются от одного юзера к другому, а потом как правильно отобразить карту в окне чата? Это должен быть `SupportMapFragment` ?

Comment: А можно немного пояснений?) Вы нажимаете на маркер, где выводится диалоговое окно с кнопочкой share и уже его можешь расшаривать по социалкам, не просто координатами а прям куском карты?

Comment: @Morozov Как в WhatsApp, вы получаете свои координаты, отправляете их другому пользователю и у другого пользователя при клике на карту, открывается карта с маркером.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Есть библиотеки, которые по заданным координатам возвращают картинку местности с заданным приближением. В таком случае можно просто отображать картинку, а при клике на нее открывать уже карту.

**Например** -  'com.github.renaudcerrato:static-maps-api:1.0.2'